# Combining vectorization and recursion in R?

Tags: r, recursion, vectorization

I am trying to combine vectorization and recursion in this implementation of the factorial function:

```
fac <- function(n) {
  ifelse(n == 1, 1, n * fac(n-1))
}

fac(6)      #720
fac(c(6,7)) #Error: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?
            #Error during wrapup: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?
```

Although ifelse is the vectorized version of if this doesn't work (see errors).

**My question**
1. Why doesn't it work?
2. How can I make it work?

**Edit:** I don't really see the connection to the proposed duplicate because the above function doesn't even work for a vector of two!

Comment: This can't work, due to how `ifelse` is implemented. Recursion is not the best strategy in R anyway. I'd suggest to implement this with Rcpp.

Comment: @Roland: I know, this is only a toy example. I was teaching a course on R today and somebody asked me about the difference between `ifelse` and `if` and I told him that `ifelse` is the vectorized version... and used this example. Then this happened and I didn't have an answer why it happened... therefore the question.

Comment: @Roland: Perhaps you could answer the first question then?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prevent infinite recursion/stack overflow error in a recursive R function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30293284/prevent-infinite-recursion-stack-overflow-error-in-a-recursive-r-function)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's look what happens:

```
fac <- function(n) {
  ifelse(n == 1, 1, {message(paste(n-1, collapse = ",")); 
                     stopifnot(n > 0); n * fac(n-1)})
}

fac(4:5)
#3,4
#2,3
#1,2
#0,1
#-1,0
# Show Traceback
# 
# Rerun with Debug
# Error: n > 0 are not all TRUE
```

As you see, the condition is never `TRUE` for all elements of `n` and thus, recursion never stops.

If all elements of `n` are equal, it works:

```
fac(c(5,5))
#4,4
#3,3
#2,2
#1,1
#[1] 120 120
```

With a small adjustment your function can work for unequal elements of `n`, too:

```
fac <- function(n) {
  ifelse(n <= 1, 1, n * fac(n-1))
}
fac(1:5)
#[1]   1   2   6  24 120
```

Comment: This is a very helpful way to look under the hood of R - Thank you and +1!

Comment: When you know how R is working internally the adjustment makes sense but when you see it just like that it seems very strange indeed...

Comment: So in this case vectorization doesn't translate into a performance gain, right?

Comment: @vonjd You'd need to bechmark it, but `ifelse` is pretty slow.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Vectorize`

```
vfac <- Vectorize(fac)
vfac(c(6,7)) 
# [1]  720 5040
```

Comment: Well, that's just a hidden loop. I'd prefer including the loop in the function defintion over this.

Comment: For some reason I didn't know `Vectorize` yet (or forgot about it?)... in any case: Thank you and +1!

Comment: @vonjd no problem, note that this won't provide efficiency and as @Roland says it is just a hidden loop, it's basically like doing `sapply(6:7, fac)` (or even slower probably). So it is good for readability when efficiency is not an issue, but it doesn't provide a speed up in the sense that `ifelse` (or other vectorized functions) does when you apply it to vectors.

Comment: @konvas: This may be the reason why you don't see it that often - on the other hand it could be more intuitively understood than all of those `apply` functions...